# How to target an iframe with javascript? (MapBox)

Tags: javascript, iframe, leaflet, mapbox

I've got a map and have created a feature layer like this:

```
window.map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.wefk232sm')
.setView([homeLatitude, homeLongitude], initialZoom);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// Pass features to the map
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

The geoJson object looks like this:

```
var geoJson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
    {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
        title: name,
        other: "text",
        'marker-color': '#54a743',
        'stroke': '#428334',
        url: link
    },
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
    }
]
};
```

I can access it on click with this:

```
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
myLayer.on('click', function(e) {
    window.open(e.layer.feature.properties.url);
});
```

When I click on the markers in the map, the url is opened in a new window. What I'm trying to achieve is to open the url in an seperate iframe.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
name="side" id="side" src="frame_start.php?((parameters in the link))">Your    
Browser does not support iframes</iframe>
```

... but I can't work out how to do this. Can anybody help me? Many thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `name` of the iframe as 2nd argument for `open`:

```
 window.open(e.layer.feature.properties.url,'side');
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much :)